# Portable way of writing /dev/fd/X in bash

Tags: bash, file-descriptors

I want to remove files before they are used, so in this example I want to unlink col1, col2 ... col1000 before `paste` starts.

```
exec 3< col1 4< col2 ... 1002< col1000
rm col1 col2 ... col1000
paste /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4 ... /dev/fd/1002
```

This works fine under GNU/Linux+bash. But `/dev/fd/X` is not portable to other systems.

I can use `bash`'s command substitution:

```
exec 3< col1 4< col2 ... 1002< col1000
rm col1 col2 ... col1000
paste <(cat <&3) <(cat <&4) ... <(cat <&1002)
```

but that will cost me a process per file.

Can I write the above in a way that would work on Bash on any system? Maybe some special Bash syntax?

Comment: `paste /proc/self/fd/3 /proc/self/fd/4`?

Comment: I just tested on HPUX: `ls /proc` gives `/proc not found`.

Comment: That's not doable by bash, and you do NOT want to know what happens under the hood with `<(...)` on systems which don't support `/dev/fd/X`. You better just create a temporary dir only you have access to (preferably in the same fs as col1 and col2), and *move* your files inside it instead of *removing* them.

Comment: With `paste` in particular, you can "halve" the problem by passing it one of the files via its stdin: `exec 0<col1; paste - col2`.

Comment: May I ask for the reason for the removal of the file? This may affect what solutions we create.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Cleanup. I need to make sure it is gone if someone takes the power.

Comment: @user414777 I have made it more clear that I am looking for a general solution by having more input files.

Comment: Just be sure to know that it won't be securely deleted. But if it is just for garbage collection, then this makes sense.

Comment: Honestly your best bet for portability is probably to reimplement this use of  `paste` as a loop in `bash`.

Comment: Worth considering, by the way, that ***semantics don't have performance costs, only implementations do*** - `<(cat ...)` might be *implemented as* forking a process, but unless `bash` ***guarantees*** the implementation detail of that always forking a child process, then a smart-enough future `bash` implementation could understand `cat` as a built-in, and could statically detect or heuristically assume that nothing depends on those `cat` commands actually running as separate processes, and then just run them as `read`/io_uring/whatever system calls in some background event loop in its process.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest portable solution would be to replace `paste` with a function that takes file descriptor numbers as arguments, and loops over them using the `read` builtin with file descriptor redirection:

```bash
paste()
{
    at_least_one_read_succeeded=true
    while $at_least_one_read_succeeded
    do
        at_least_one_read_succeeded=false
        first_fd=true
        for fd in "$@"
        do
            if ! $first_fd
            then
                printf '\t'
            fi
            if IFS= read -r line <&"$fd"
            then
                at_least_one_read_succeeded=true
            fi
            printf '%s' "$line"
            first_fd=false
        done
        printf '\n'
    done
}
```

The biggest downside is that this will be orders of magnitude slower, because the shell's `read` builtin has no choice but to do a separate `read` system call **for each byte**. Similarly, each invocation of the `printf` command has to do at least one `write` system call (in theory, someone could write a shell which would be able to optimize the I/O in this situation, by using the same analysis that optimizing compilers and JIT VMs do, but no such shell exists currently). In many situations the difference would still be negligible on modern hardware, but since your example includes a thousand files, you might actually see a performance drop which matters in your use-case.

Of course, there's nothing besides respect for your time and energy stopping you from rolling your own buffered I/O in the shell. For example, you could use `dd bs=4096 count=1` to read 4096 bytes at a time into a separate variable for each FD, and then grab lines from that until you run out of newline characters. For example, you could create a bash array named `buffers`, read into it with `buffers[$fd]=$(dd bs=4096 count=1 <$&fd)`, grab the first line from it with `${buffers[$fd]%%'$\n'*}` (substitution with deletion from the back greedily matching a substring of a newline followed by any characters), and so on. Honestly, if you're considering that, and if not leaving those `col` files on disk is so important, you might even consider just reading the entire contents of those column files into `bash` variables - I don't know your data sizes, but if your system allows `bash` to allocate that much and if `bash` itself handles it, then if it's *really* important to keep those files from staying on disk, maybe it's important enough to not even have those contents hit named files at all.

---

But taking a step back for a moment, maybe this is good enough instead?

```bash
paste col1 col2 ... col1000 &  # background `paste`
# optionally, put a tiny sleep here
rm col1 col2 ... col1000
wait  # wait for `paste` to finish
```

Because honestly, there's always a time window during which `col*` files could fail to get cleaned up (what if power is cut before your `rm` even in your code where the `rm` runs before the `paste`?). Is it really unacceptably worse if that window is longer by <=1 second (or even less than a millisecond might be plenty on modern hardware) while `paste` starts up and hits all of its arguments with the `open` system call?

---

Yet another thing to consider is using a temporary file system. Many operating systems provide an in-memory file system at some path. For example, on almost every Linux distro, `/run` is a `tmpfs` mount, and each user usually gets a private directory there at `/run/$(id -u)`: if you lose power or otherwise reboot or turn off the box, nothing in `tmpfs` will survive. I don't know what other systems you need to run on, but it's worth checking if those systems have a temporary in-memory file system or guaranteed-to-be-wiped-upon-reboot-by-the-OS directory somewhere.